# Is it possible to build a RewriteRule regex with database values?

Tags: php, .htaccess

When my client adds a page to the site, the new pagename should be appended to a RewiteRule regex. So with, for instance fwrite(), I would like PHP to change that RewiteRule regex with values retracted from the database. If this could be done, are there any pitfalls in the process?

> Edit: handling in a PHP script would be the solution, if there would'nt be more to it... 
>   First  domain/index.php?page=pagename is 301 redirected to "domain/pagename"
>   to warn the visitor this page is permanently moved - (this is the old
>   PUBLIC location of the URL and should give this 301). Then requests
>   like "domain/pagename" (the new public location), would be
>   silently,internally rewritten to domain/index.php?page=pagename where
>   verification takes place and a 404 is given when not valid. But just
>   the key, the "page" part of ?page=pagename, is static and can be
>   verified and will give a 404 directly from within the .htaccess . Now,
>   requests like domain/index.php?page=crap will first nicely give a 301
>   like the valid domain/index.php?page=pagename does, and only when
>   arrived in the index.php can be identified as crap. So there is still
>   a need to get the pagenames from the database to inside the .htaccess.

This is a sample of the .htacces content to give some background to this problem:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/testsite/404.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /testsite/

## block craprequests without extension like domain/crap > 404  
# The requests domain/pagename that do not go to existing pages, will now be redirected with a 302 to index.php?page=pagename and only then give a 404 through the errorcheck in the code.
# This should be done here, with a RewriteCond regex with database content
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !404.php$
RewriteRule .* 404.php [R=404,L]

## block-direct-queries ##
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !marker=1$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=(.*)
RewriteRule ^.*$ %1? [R=301,L]


## strip-extensions ##
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !404.php$
RewriteRule ^([\w+%*\d*\+*\-*]+)\.(php[\s]{0,3}|htm[\s]{0,3}|html[\s]{0,3})$ $1 [R=301,L]

## put-querystring
RewriteRule ^([\w\-_]+)\/?$ index.php?page=$1&marker=1 [L]
```

Comment: yes you can do that (it not easy but you can do it)

Comment: Please define that more closely. Include a sample `.htaccess` and how that sample should look like after modification.

Comment: Sounds like a generic rewrite rule to route everything through a PHP controller script is the answer here, rather than modifying the .htaccess every time the site layout is modified (which has some fairly hefty security implications as well).

Comment: @C.A.Vuyk Could you add that to the question and format it properly, please? It's no use to post code as a comment.

Comment: @DaveRandom at the time the script is reached, the http status is wrong already.

Comment: @C.A.Vuyk Why? The headers are not sent until you actually output something, and before this time you can manipulate the response code from PHP. Even if you want to redirect valid requests to the correct resource, this could be done from PHP.

Comment: @DaveRandom just now found the cause of the problem: the last Rule had a [R] flag for testing purposes. That's where the 302 came from...
In this way dynamic .htaccess is indeed not necessary. Thanks all.

Comment: Another mistake was to put the "http://" in the ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/testsite/404.php. This will give a redirect and a 302 status instead of 404. Also see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#errordocument

Comment: @DaveRandom It would be the solution to use a script if there would'nt be other circumstances, please see the edits above. There is still a need to get the pagenames from the database to inside the .htaccess. –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will most likely be possible (although writing permissions may be an issue). However wouldn't it be a better way to route all requests from the client through the index.php file and let PHP handle the routing.

This way you will be maximum flexible and you don't have to do "hacky" stuff.

**EDIT**

All forms of redirect can be done from PHP. E.g. an example of a `301` redirect:

```
header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header ('Location: http://example.com/new/path'); // note the full address
exit();
```

Please see [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) for more information about the use of `header()`.

Comment: The point is, that is not possible when you first catch URL requests that are like: domain/pagename and then silently rewrite them with a RewriteRule to domain/index.php?page=pagename. You have to know which pages are allowed from within .htaccess otherwise crap requests like domain/crap will also redirect while I want those to give a 404 status.

Comment: @C.A.Vuyk So give the 404 from PHP ([`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)). It's much, much, much easier than trying to alter the .htaccess every time you make a change to the site.

Comment: You're right that it is much easier. The case is, that due to the rewriting,any form of domain/pagename first gives a status of 302, while the wrong ones should immediately give 404.

Comment: That isn't a problem. PHP can add a 404 header without any problem.

Comment: That would be the solution, if there would'nt be more to it... Please follow the edit in the question about 301 redirect of "domain/pagename" (the old PUBLIC location of the URL which should give 301) to domain/index.php?page=pagename.
So there is still a need to get the pagenames from the database to inside the .htaccess.

Comment: You can also do 301 redirects in PHP.

Comment: You're right, I think sometimes I'm looking too much for a solution in one direction.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry to keep repeating this back to you, but there just isn't a need for storing the page name in the .htaccess. This can all be done much more simply in PHP.

The only rewrite rule you need is this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?index\.php$
RewriteRule .* /index.php [L,QSA]
```

Now, in PHP, you can do something like this:

```
// The important point here is that $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] contains the actual
// path the user typed into their browser, which is what you are interested in

if (strtolower(basename(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH))) === 'index.php') {
    // The user directly requested index.php
    if (!empty($_GET['page']) || value_of_page_is_crap()) {
        // The user requested a bad page
        header("{$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']} 404 Not Found");
    } else {
        // Redirect to correct URL
        header("{$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']} 301 Moved Permanently");
        header("Location: http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}/{$_GET['page']}");
    }
    exit;
}

// The request is allowed to continue
$requestedPage = pathinfo($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

The .htaccess will route every single request blindly through PHP, where much more precise logic than mod_rewrite's clunky PCRE-based rules can be used.

The PHP script examines the URI the user typed into their address bar in the browser. If they directly requested `index.php`, it will check whether `$_GET['page']` contains a sensible value and if it does, redirect them to the correct URL, if not respond with a 404. If the user did not request index.php directly, the script can continue. I have added an example line to show how you *could* extract the value of the page they requested, but how you continue on from here is up to you.

Comment: You're right! Thanks very much for the explaination. This can be done in more ways so I see. I would have give you the accept but PeeHaa was first, upvoted now.